# Configuring child loggers

Tags: python, logging

Every time I think I understand the logging module, gremlins come in and change the way it works.  (Ok, I'll admit, that gremlin may be me changing my code.)

What am I doing wrong here?

```
> ipython
> import logging
> log = logging.Logger("base")
> log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

> log.critical("Hi")
Hi

> log2 = log.getChild("ment")

> log2.critical("hi")
No handlers could be found for logger "base.ment"
```

I could have sworn that in the past, I was able to use child loggers without additional configuration...

Comment: Try it in a new session. It works for me using ipython, and also as a script.

Comment: Not working for me either in cPython 2.7.2.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the default configuration of a `StreamHandler`... When I create `log`, add handler to `log`, then create `log2`, I get `No handlers`, but if I create `log2` first then add the handler to `log`, logging to `log2` doesn't error (though it doesn't print anything either).

Comment: @unutbu: Hmmm...  that *is* a new session.  I included the 'ipython' command-line at the top to indicate that.  That you're able to run this with no problem gives me a bad feeling.  I'm running Python 2.7.1 & IPython 0.10.  Been that way for a *long* time, so that wouldn't seem to be the problem.  I *know* its has to do with my code...

Comment: @unutbu: When I run it via a script and Python 2.7.1 I get the same behavior.  May I ask what version are you running?

Comment: @JS.: I made a typo -- When I correct it, I get the same "No handlers" error as you using Python 2.7.2 and IPython 0.10.2.

Comment: @unutbu: Crickey man!  What was the typo?  Maybe that's the solution!  ;-)

Comment: @JS.: LOL, does typing `log.critical('hi')` twice count as a solution? :)

Comment: For anyone trying to figure out logging, I **highly** recommend using Brandon Rhodes' [logging_tree](https://pypi.org/project/logging_tree/).  It is greatly helpful in figuring out why logging isn't working the way you think it should.  ```import logging_tree; logging_tree.printout()``` is all you need.  Thank you so much for making and sharing logging_tree Brandon!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you change

```
log = logging.Logger('base')
```

to

```
log = logging.getLogger('base')
```

then it works:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('base')
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
log.critical('Hi')
log2 = log.getChild('ment')
log2.critical('hi')
```

yields

```
Hi
hi
```

Comment: I was just about to try that... good catch and thanks for the help!  +1

Comment: Argh, I just tracked this down... Yeah, the logging module invisibly proxies through `logging.Manager` to create loggers.  When you directly create a logger with `logging.Logger()` you short-circuit the system and things go haywire.

Comment: I dug through my mercurial versions and that's exactly what happened.  I "cleaned up" my logging code and typed "Logger" instead of "getLogger".  @sr2222: Thanks for chasing down the cause.  It does help to know why it failed.  I can now shift my mental model from "load logging and create a logger" to "load logging and create a child logger".  +1. Thanks!

Comment: I would say more, "load logging, instantiate the base logger (explicitly or implicitly), spawn descendants from root and its descendants."  It is interesting to have looked through the code now though.  I know now that even if your code only creates a logger named 'a.b.c.d.e.f' explicitly, the logging module will create loggers for a, b, c, d, and e automatically.  Good to remember when you are looking for optimizations...

Answer (score 3):

More detail: You are using the module wrong.  :)  From looking at the module code, it looks like they don't expect you to ever create a `logging.Logger()` directly.  Many of the functions available directly on the module (ex `getLogger()`) and the methods on `logging.Logger()` (ex `getChild()`) actually proxy through an instance of `logging.Manager` that the module creates on import.  When you create a `Logger` with `logging.Logger()` directly, you are actually creating a `Logger` instance outside of the `Manager`.  When you subsequently call `log.getChild()`, the module is actually creating the new logger inside the `Manager`, but with the name of the `Manager`-external logger appended to the front of the logger name.  So your handler added to `log` is not in the `Manager` with the spawned child, and thus the handler doesn't work.  I am a little confused still though on why adding a handler to `log` before or after creating `log2` causes logging against `log2` to behave differently.  I don't see what's causing that...

Comment: :"with logging.Logger() directly, you are actually creating a Logger instance outside of the Manager. When you subsequently call log.getChild(), the module is actually creating the new logger inside the Manager"  Interesting.  And makes sense.  I must remember to always think "create sub-logger"... even when creating *my* program's "first" logger.